# ¿Cómo se pueden crear multihilos en Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee, hilos

¿Es posible crear multihilos en un contenedor Java EE como GlassFish?
Mi intención es crear una aplicación donde los usuarios pueden lanzar capturas de datos de una red social, entonces cada usuario lanzaría un nuevo hilo con los parámetros que desea para recuperar la informacion de la red social.
Todos estos hilos estarían limitados en número para no agotar la memoria del servidor.

¿Cómo puedo crear varios hilos en Java EE y que estos una vez que el usuario sale de la aplicacion se queden en ejecucion en segundo plano hasta que el  usuario los cierre?

¿Una solución puede ser los job de GlassFish?

Answer (score 3):

Dependiendo de tu tipo de aplicación, puedes generar los hilos manualmente o que el contenedor los genere y administre por ti. Usualmente sucede el segundo caso donde el contenedor, para tu caso GlassFish, los crea administra y termina al atender una petición de usuario, esto es, una petición HTTP.

Si te refieres a si puedes crear hilos en un servlet, sí puedes pero **no es recomendado** puesto que este hilo no será administrado por el servidor de aplicaciones, de manera que cualquier labor de manejo de recursos, monitoreo y otras características las deberás implementar tú mismo. Además, es muy fácil destruir tu aplicación al realizar ese tipo de acciones. Igual aquí tienes un ejemplo (extremadamente básico, adaptarlo a tu necesidad, no  utilizar código así en producción):

```
@WebServlet("ruta")
public class MiServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        new Thread( () -> System.out.println("hello world from thread") ).start();
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, tienes los Enterprise Java Bean, también conocidos como EJBs. En la especificación de EJB se explica que **no se permite** abrir hilos en estos componentes. Utilizar un código similar al explicado arriba en un EJB resultará en una excepción.

Para tu caso, lo que te convendría sería utilizar una arquitectura por mensajes como JMS. La comunicación por JMS es asíncrona, de manera que el servidor de aplicaciones abrirá un hilo por ti al iniciar la comunicación y atender la petición. Esto lo puedes lograr a través de un EJB de tipo `@MessageDriven`, tal como se muestra en este tutorial: [Java EE 7 -- JMS 2.0 With Glassfish v4](http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/05/java-ee-7-jms-2-0-with-glassfish-v4/). No puedo proveer ejemplos de mi cabeza para este caso puesto que no lo he trabajado con GlassFish sino con JBoss, Active MQ como manejador de colas y Spring.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero una de las cosas que necesito es que estos hilos no se cierren una vez que finaliza la peticion del usuario, sino que esten constantemente en ejecucion. Si el usuario sale de la aplicacion el hilo tiene que seguir en funcionamiento. La unica solucion viable creo que es la API de Concurrencia de Java ee 7

Comment: @IvanGarciaMiranda lo que te comento lo resuelve JMS. Esos hilos los abre y administra el servidor de aplicaciones y seguirán ejecutandose de manera asíncrona a la funcionalidad que ha solicitado el usuario. El hilo se terminará cuando la tarea asociada a esa cola termine su ejecución, de manera que cumple con lo que solicitas. Te recomendaría leer más sobre este tema.